# AWS Parameter Store result as list in CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to get my S3 bucket names dynamically, instead of list them directly in CloudFormation, using the SSM Parameter Store "StringList". but then in CF template, I have to use the SSM value, so when I am creating the stack, it does not show me the value but instead the key, also I was not successful to resolve the SSM as a list.

Steps:

Create a parameter store as StringList

```
Name: /s3/lists
Value: sample1,sample2
```

CloudFormation Template

```
Parameters:
  myS3Buckets:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<List<String>>
    AllowedValues: ['{{resolve:ssm:/s3/lists}}']
```

then see the list of S3 buckets when I am creating the stack.

## Update #1

to explain myself better, here is the full example:

```
Parameters:
  InstanceTypeDefault:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - t1.micro
      - t2.nano
      - t2.micro
      - t2.small

  InstanceTypesDynamic:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<List<String>>
    AllowedValues:
      - /ec2/lists

Resources:
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      ImageId: ami-0742b4e673072066f
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceTypesDynamic
```

in the normal way we set the AllowedValues like `InstanceTypeDefault` but I am trying instead of editing template each time, get the list either via API call or have them in SSM Parameter Store.

I'd like to make t possible to see the `InstanceTypesDynamic` like the `InstanceTypeDefault` dropdown list with `AllowedValues`.

[image]

Comment: You are trying to mix https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html - I do not think this is going to work for the reason that is simply not supported.

Comment: @luk2302 what about to use the result directly in resources, also not possible? Is there any way to get the list of any resource config dynamically like (ec2 types, imageIDs, ...) I am using my template in service Catalog so I do not upload my template each time. I am trying to avoid to have a big list in my template and update my template each time I am creating new resource.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-ssm) states the following:

> For SSM Parameters, the reference-key segment is composed of the parameter name and version number.

And

> CloudFormation doesn't support using parameter labels or public parameters in dynamic references.
> A parameter label is a user-defined alias to help you manage different versions of a parameter.

So you're not referencing the parameter correctly, you should include the version of the parameter in your template: e.g., `{{resolve:ssm:/s3/lists:1}}`

Comment: true, but this not resolve my problem. I've updated my question